# Completely Disable/Remove "Welcome to Ubuntu!"/"Connect Your Online Accounts" Window

Tags: gnome, online-accounts

I am in the process of making a live USB for use in an IT environment, where the use will need to be very plug-and-play, with little to no interruption. I'm onto QOL development, and I am trying to remove the following screen, which shows up whenever the user signs in:

[image]

I have followed the steps listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1576565/how-to-remove-gnome-online-accounts-integration), which said to remove `/usr/share/applications/gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop`, however that did not work. I have also attempted a full uninstall of the `online-accounts` package, `sudo apt remove --purge gnome-online-accounts`, however this did not work either.

I have also removed `gnome-initial-setup` from `/usr/share/applications` as that is what the window was named:

[image]

Again, however, this did not make the window disappear.

I am building off of Ubuntu 21.04, and am using Cubic to make the live USB.

One solution I had pondered on was; would it be possible to find the `.desktop` file of a running application?

Comment: I don't know what I'm talking about, plus I am on I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, so my landscape may differ from yours. Nevertheless, for disabling this, I would look into the `gsettings` schemas, on 20.04 easily explorable with the `dconf-editor` app. If you could find the setting to disable this in gsettings, then maybe that would be an important step. As for code, on 20.04 I seem to have a bunch of `*.gschema.xml` files in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` — something tells me that these have something to do with what shows up in `gsettings` / `dconf-editor`...